# Cannot log in to Samba shares on Windows from different domain

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, samba

I'm trying to connect to a Samba share on a VirtualBox'ed Windows 7 that is connected to an openSUSE host in bridged mode. For reasons [beyond my comprehension](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/181290-cannot-access-certain-network-resource-through-itunes.html) I cannot use the shared folders feature, so I'm using Samba instead.

I configured a share through openSUSE's Samba server configuration tool:

```
[iTunes]
        inherit acls = Yes
        path = /home/myusername/iTunes
        read only = No
        valid users = myusername
```

I also set a password for this user using `smbpasswd -a myusername`. I can go to `smb://192.168.1.6` on the host machine and log in to the share successfully, but on Windows 7 I see this:

[image: Samba error]

What am I doing wrong? I can connect to the shares list without any problems. It's just the login that doesn't work.

---

**Update**: I noticed that my Samba server is part of the *WORKGROUP* domain.

```
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.7-1.17.1-2505-SUSE-SL11.4-x86_64]                                                                                                                     

        Sharename       Type      Comment                                                                                                                                                            
        ---------       ----      -------                                                                                                                                                            
        iTunes          Disk                                                                                                                                                                         
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 3.5.7-1.17.1-2505-SUSE-SL11.4-x86_64)                                                                                                           
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.7-1.17.1-2505-SUSE-SL11.4-x86_64]                                                                                                                     

        Server               Comment                                                                                                                                                                 
        ---------            -------                                                                                                                                                                 

        Workgroup            Master                                                                                                                                                                  
        ---------            -------
```

However, when I have to log in on Windows I see this...

[image: Samba login]

Is this a problem? If so, how do I route around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People in `#samba` on `irc.freenode.net` recommended that I create an account on the server with the same username and password as the client I'm logging in with.

While this is not an ideal solution, I will use this method until someone can tell me how I can log in with my own account. Being able to log in with my own account would eliminate a lot of annoying file privilege administration.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you already have a connection to the server using a different username from your Windows PC. Perhaps you already have a mapped network drive to 192.168.1.6 where you specified a different username for the connection.

You can't have more than one username connecting to a multiple shares on a server from the one client.

To see a list of shares on the remote computer, try:

```
NET VIEW \\192.168.1.6
```

Try disconnecting any and all current connections. See http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html.

Disconnect from a share:

```
NET USE [driveletter:] /DELETE
```

Disconnect from a share and close all resources (undocumented):

```
NET USE [driveletter:] /DELETE /Y
```

Once you have all connections disconnected, try connecting to iTunes again.

Comment: Currently I do not have any mapped network resources and I'm still getting the error. http://i.imgur.com/TOUBc.png Is there a way to close all open Samba connections on the server side? I've already tried restarting the server.